# create a UIImageView that crops an image and displays only 100w 100h at 50x and 200y

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am trying to create a box that pops up in my xcode app that just displays an image of that size. I have the following

```
UIImageView *newView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"beach.jpg"]];
```

but this creates the full size image and just shows it. How would I only show it as 100w by 100h at 50 over and 200 down? Would I use CGRect?

Also, can I make it so that clicking it causes it to disappear?

**edit #1** 
I don't want to resize down the image - would rather just pull the 100 squared pixels and place them in a frame.

Comment: You need to add UITapGestureRecognizer on the UIImageView for the tapping.

Comment: To the edit: Then set the bounds instead of the frame. You will not need the contentMode, but you need to set clipsToBounds to YES.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Please try using the following code.

```
MyImageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; 
MyImageview.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Yes... These 2 needs to be set also, along with the frame.

Comment: thx P, this is resizing down the image - any way to get the original size?

Comment: Did you try MyImageview.contentMode =UIViewContentModeTopLeft ;

Comment: Thnx so much @ParamasivanSamuttiram.

Comment: Equivalent to setting "Clip Subviews" in interface designer

Answer (score 15):

You can crop image with below code:

```
CGRect cropRegion = CGRectMake(50, 200, 100, 100);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"beach.jpg"];
CGImageRef subImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, cropRegion);
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:subImage];
UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:croppedImage];
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Nice to see a solution that doesn't require creating whole new contexts and things just for a little crop.

Answer (score 14):

You can also achieve the cropping effect by checking the **Clip Subviews** option in the storyboard.

[image]

Or equivalent settings in code with **Swift 4+**

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: @Mansuu.... it should work. If not, try doing this in code https://stackoverflow.com/a/13715487/1035008, which should be equivalent to these two settings.

Comment: You a wizard. saved my day :)